# Quantizing timeline data for averaging and histograms

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have some raw spreadsheet data that's in a format, like:

```
12/7/2016 3:07:00, 88.05,
12/7/2016 3:08:00, 89.10,
12/7/2016 3:13:00, 87.00,
etc
```

These data points are not sampled at a regular interval, but are randomly collected throughout the day.

Using Google Sheets I'm able to graph this easily onto a Timeline chart.  This puts the values at the correct position on the timeline and takes the uneven sampling intervals into account.

I would like to generate a histogram of the timeline data while taking into account the timestamps and calculate an average value over a timeframe.  I believe if I simply run this through the built-in histogram chart or select my data values and run it through an averaging function, it will be skewed by the uneven sampling intervals.

What's the easiest way to quantize the sampling intervals (ideally within Google Sheets) for generating my histogram and averaging?

or

Is there a built-in method to generate histograms/averaging of values while taking timestamp data into account, eliminating the need for quantized data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the appropriate average as follows (assuming your data is in the range A2:B50)

```
=sum(arrayformula((A3:A50-A2:A49)*(B3:B50+B2:B49)/2))/(A50-A2)
```

This formula implements the [Trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule): the value assigned to each time interval is the average of observed values at the ends of that interval.

There isn't a built-in "weighted histogram" tool, so it appears that needs re-sampling to create a representative histogram. Here is one way to resample. Let's say you want 20 samples; then in C2 enter

```
=arrayformula(A2+(row(1:20)-1)*(A50-A2)/19)
```

to get 20 uniformly distributed time values. (Division by 19 because of the fence-post distinction.) Then in D2,

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(C2:C21, A2:B50, 2))
```

will lookup a value for each sample time. Then you can build a histogram from column D.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks!